# .gitlab-ci.yaml regex detect dot

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I've and pipeline job name "validjob", i want it to check if $VAR CI variable contains dot using regex.

```
validjob:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $VAR =~ "/(\.)/"
  script:
    - exit 1
  allow_failure: false
```

I've tried above piece but it didn't work. i use regex like "(.)" , "/./" ... and some kind of variations.

So what is the right way to detect dot

Comment: I don’t think you’re supposed to quote the regex. Have you tried `$VAR =~ /(\.)/`? (Or just `$VAR =~ /\./`; what would a group do here?)

Comment: it worked without quote thanks @Biffen